# Recode in dplyr to change labels resulting in Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to recode variables and receive the following error message.

```
data$x<-recode(data$x,"1=0")
Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::recode(data$x, "1=0")
 2. dplyr:::recode.character(data$x, "1=0")
 3. dplyr:::bad_pos_args(bad, "must be named, not unnamed.")
 4. dplyr:::glubort(fmt_pos_args(pos_args), ..., .envir = .envir)
```

Since I just started working with R I do not know, how to continue. I am very grateful for ideas how to continue/ resolve the problem!

Comment: Try dplyr::recode(KiGGS2$MNfernCmetrisch, "1"="0")

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @stefan: Thanks for your feedback - I still receive the message Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed."